# Trouble connecting spring application to Mysql Database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hi I'm relatively new to spring working through this spring tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

I'm using the code provided and have set up the MySql database as suggested, however using cURL command gives the following error:

> > curl localhost:8080/demo/add -d name=First -d email=someemail@someemailprovider.com                      <!doctype html>HTTP Status 500 ÔÇô Internal Server Errorbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}
> >
> > ## HTTP Status 500 ÔÇô Internal Server Error

MainController:

```
package Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import Repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.demo.Model.*;

@Controller // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class MainController {
  @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
         // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @PostMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY POST Requests
  public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
      , @RequestParam String email) {
    // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
    // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

    User n = new User();
    n.setName(name);
    n.setEmail(email);
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "Saved";
  }

  @GetMapping(path="/all")
  public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
    return userRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.example.demo.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  private String email;

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package Repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.demo.Model.User;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

Gradle.build

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Console Logs,

doesn't seem to be picking up database `2020-08-06 16:38:44.272  INFO 17940 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 9ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.`

````
2020-08-06 16:38:46.196  WARN 17940 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The server time zone value 'GMT Summer Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
2020-08-06 16:39:18.344  INFO 17940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-06 16:39:18.344  INFO 17940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-08-06 16:39:18.348  INFO 17940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
2020-08-06 16:39:18.363 ERROR 17940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not create JPA EntityManager; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]] with root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

```
2020-08-06 16:39:18.369 ERROR 17940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

```
2020-08-06 16:39:18.370 ERROR 17940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not create JPA EntityManager; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```
````

Comment: Is there some error in the console? Can you paste it here ?

Comment: I've edited it to include some of the console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to append the below onto datasource

```
?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

credit
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i4t-SL1VsU

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code

1 - You have not added @Repository annotation to your repository class. So, system is not able to find any repository interfaces

2 - You are making wrong curl command. You are sending name and email as body parameters. You should ideally send them as query parameters. This is what is expected when you use @RequestParam in controller

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/demo/add?name=First&email=email@dds.com'
```

Comment: i've added the @Repository annotation , the curl command provides the following output:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'localhost
'email' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I have copied your code (with @Repository) to my local and it is working perfectly for for me.  below is the curl command that worked for me curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/demo/add?name=First&email=email@dds.com'

Comment: Did you replaced  ${MYSQL_HOST:localhost} in application.properties with actual mysql address and credentials

Comment: i'm using spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/

and using the curl prompt gives:
(6) Could not resolve host: 'localhost
'email' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Will do, just setting it up

Comment: postman is most widely used API unit testing tool. You can test your APIs without writing any curl command. In your case, I am pretty sure that issue is not with controller. It is with the curl command

Comment: running postman with: localhost:8080/demo/add?name=First&email=email@dds.com as a post request yields a internal server error

Comment: What is the error now. I copied your code and it was working fine for me. So no problem with your code. Might be you are doing very minor miss

Comment: when I post something it generates this in the console:
2020-08-06 19:02:35.112 ERROR 12568 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not create JPA EntityManager; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Comment: I am not sure. Suggestion would be to download any working code and try by your own where you are going wrong. There are many public repos available - one of them is - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic

Answer (score 1):

By the error in the console, I think you're missing this in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Chose the dialect matching your mysql version.